# Nested Urls throwing 404 error

Tags: python, django

I have built a guide website. 
Each guide is made of steps.
Each step is made of tasks.

To go the next step, you need to complete the task and then to the next, until there are no more steps.

Example views and URL:

`/1` should show you guide1

`/1/3` should show the step3 of guide1

`/1/3/5` should show task5 of step3 in guide1

I want the URLs to be like this: `/1/3/6` (guide1/step3/task6)

I got it to work when I go to `/1`. Then it shows the view of the guide.
But when I go to `/1/1` or `1/1/1` I get a 404 error saying that the guide does not exist.

I need help. Here is my code:

Urls.py for app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<guide_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.taskoftheday, name="taskoftheday"),
    url(r'(?P<guide_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<step.sequence_num>[0-9]+)/$', views.taskoftheday_step, name="taskoftheday_step"),
    url(r'(?P<guide_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<step.sequence_num>[0-9]+)/(?P<task.sequence_num>[0-9]+)/$', views.taskoftheday_task, name="taskoftheday_task"),
]
```

urls.py for project

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^taskoftheday/', include('taskoftheday.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('taskoftheday.urls')),
    url(r'^analytics/', include('analytics.urls')),
    url(r'^progress/', include('progress.urls')),
    url(r'^goals/', include('goals.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'thanks/', views.thanks),
    url(r'thanks_again/', views.thanks_again),
    url(r'^$', views.landing_page),
]
```

models.py

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    guide_category = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    guide_why = models.TextField()
    guide_how = models.TextField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Step(models.Model):
    guide = models.ForeignKey(Guide, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("guide", "sequence_number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    task_img = models.ImageField()
    task_task = models.TextField()
    task_description = models.TextField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("step", "sequence_number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def taskoftheday(request, guide_id):
    try:
        guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=guide_id)
    except Guide.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Guide does not exist")
    return render(request, 'taskoftheday/taskoftheday.html', {'guide': guide})

def taskoftheday_step(request, guide_id, step_id):
    try:
        guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=guide_id)
        step = Step.objects.get(guide=guide, sequence_number=step_id)
    except Step.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Step does not exist")
    return render(request, 'taskoftheday/taskoftheday_step.html', {'step': step})

def taskoftheday_task(request, guide_id, step_id, task_id):
    try:
        guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=guide_id)
        step = Step.objects.get(guide=guide, sequence_number=step_id)
        task = Task.objects.get(step=step, sequence_number=task_id)
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Task does not exist")
    return render(request, 'taskoftheday/taskoftheday_task.html', {'task': task})
```

Comment: What's your question exactly ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers My question is how to get the views showing and using the url pattern. It don't work as it is. :)

Comment: Please post the full traceback.